# CDAHttpException fetching one resource on Contentful

Tags: java, contentful, contentful-api

I am trying to retrieve a resource on a contentful space.

When I try to do the query with `.one` method, I have returned a

```
com.contentful.java.cda.CDAHttpException: null
```

What may be wrong?

```
    FetchQuery<CDAEntry> fetch = client.fetch(CDAEntry.class);
    fetch = fetch.where("content_type", content_type);
    fetch = fetch.where("locale", "it_IT");

    // line below launch com.contentful.java.cda.CDAHttpException: null
    final CDAEntry entry = fetch.one(resourceId);
```

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? I would especially be interested in the full StackTrace of the exception (make sure to remove sensitive data) and\or the client initialization (make sure to remove token and space id). Also are you using a proxy server in between, or are you directly communicating with Contentful?

Comment: The problem was the incorrect locale language